# receiving mail from gmail through IMAP in rails

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail, mime, quoted-printable

I am trying to fetching  mail from gmail ..but i am facing a serious problem during saving mail into database. the body content are comming with "=" after saving when continous line.  as bellow ---

```
            1206979905221152897hs_cos_wrapper m=
     2897hs_cos_wrapper_widget m_1206979905221152897hs_cos_wrapp=
er_type style=3D"color:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inh=
 <p style=3D"margin-bottom:1em">All my best,<br> Mitchell</p>=
  <p style=3D"margin-bottom:1em">P.S. If you ha just reply t=
   il.=C2=A0When you&#39;re ready to upgrade, head to the <a href=3D=
  "http://wwv.lucidchart.com/e1t/c/qYC2Db8rk0/*W9fFq-316bx3F=
   W8CWyzp3DpNLV0/5/f18dQhb0S1Wd2Rwh5hbnMC51QVv9W7Hwjq86wWWGZW7=
   vQrRW6Qxg9Z686lDXN2rRW6BC5sBzW5SYlQv675mnXW4CmKYY8D95T9=
    1QPK5fVJjqh62qGt4tW59CYkB2GJgtzW2CnNzP4Nl11wW25fJr-6rNw=
    1bGRVbJk6q3v7J8mW27C-VC1FY2gGN6MVfyPPzMd8W1BHsPt6vz=
   pHt1q4V4_W16sdWz6QH55-N7mZJVzgBNVkW5XTLDH4mr1_8W5XVC028=
    8wcs95JMf33W8qC3t312Syl5W1wRxFp1C1pg3W2xZfwK4jjGmtW6KV-4P3DmD0SMzTM2=
  rW1htky14LlZRgW1xhbdr802V94W6DjZCs5DKYwwW8pqCdK8p4315W5TcLJb4l7QQ3W1hW=
  SzKlg-8W6306Xl4bGXglVJJ2MB7GT0xLN58Q5QDyl2mZW6W8_KH4B6wtPW6_h=
  ndB5y83PqVFwc094vFyxmW5mSySS97kT7Df4wGTd902">pricing page=
 </a>.</p></div>
                           how can i sefe from this prolem?
```

Comment: MIME "quoted-printable"

Comment: there is so many extention in mime ... RFC 2045, RFC 2046, RFC 2047, RFC 4288, RFC 4289 and RFC 2049;  RFC 1521 and RFC 1522. which is the exactly need?nd how?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable